# Add prefix and suffix to list values R

Tags: r

My R Code

```
data <- read.csv('filename.csv')
typof(data)
[1] "list"

str(data)
    'data frame' : 9 obs. of 10 variables
    $Name: Factor w/9 levels "Name 1", "Name 2",....
    $Column2: chr "","Text1","","Text2"
    $Column3: chr "Text2","Text3","","Text1"
    $Column4: chr "","","","Text1"
#and so on
```

Requirement:

All I want is in `$Column2`, `$Column3`, `$Column4`,... whereever there is non blank value, add a prefix (`Here this is`) and suffix (`completed`). 
So considering above `data Column2`, 2nd row which presently has value `"Text1"` should become `"Here this is Text1 completed."`

Similarly in `Column3: 1st, 2nd and 4th cell` will need to add the prefix and suffix value.

I **don't want to use loop**, unless and untill required/necssary.

My attempt:

I have tried few attempt such as `interaction`, `mget`, `append` and few more but nothing seems to work.

Comment: have you tried [mutate_each](https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/man/summarise_each.html) and [paste](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html) ?

Comment: see my answer, it does this in one line of code, its tested as well.

Comment: @ZeeshanArif Your answer operates over a single column, not the whole data sets. Also, similar answers were already posted (that loop over columns too)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would vectorize this as follows

```
indx <- which(data[, -1] != "", arr.ind = TRUE) # Find all non-empty incidences 
data[, -1][indx] <- paste("Here this is", data[, -1][indx], "completed.")
```

Comment: `indx` also takes column 1 into consideration, where I don't want to apply the condition. How do I change this?

Answer (score 3):

This will work for the first 4 columns

```
apply(data[,2:4],2,function(x) ifelse(x != "",paste("Here this is ",x," completed."),x))
```

Assuming that the prefix and suffix are the same for each column. It does return a matrix, but it easy enough to convert that to a dataframe.
Hope it helps.

Edit: just now realized that your data is in a list, so you need `lapply` or `sapply`. Something like:

```
sapply(data,function(x) ifelse(x != "",paste("Here this is ",x," completed."),x))[,2:4]
```

also returns a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `set` which assigns in place without any copying

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
for(j in 2:ncol(data)){
      set(data, i = which(data[[j]]!=""), 
                j = j,
                value = paste("Here there is ",  data[[j]][data[[j]]!=""], " completed."))
    }
data
#     Name                          Column2                          Column3
#1: Name 1                                  Here there is  Text1  completed.
#2: Name 2 Here there is  Text1  completed.                                 
#3: Name 3 Here there is  Text2  completed. Here there is  Text2  completed.
#4: Name 4                                  Here there is  Text3  completed.
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(Name = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Name 1", "Name 2", 
"Name 3", "Name 4"), class = "factor"), Column2 = c("", "Text1", 
 "Text2", ""), Column3 = c("Text1", "", "Text2", "Text3")), .Names = c("Name", 
 "Column2", "Column3"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `lapply` function (which is also a loop):

```
# dummy data
df1 <- mtcars[1:5, 1:3]
# add blanks
df1[2,2] <- ""
df1
#                    mpg cyl disp
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0      160
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360

# add prefix and suffix
res <- cbind(df1[, 1, drop = FALSE],
             data.frame(
               lapply(df1[, -1], function(i)
                 ifelse(i == "", i, paste("Here this is", i, "completed.")))))


res
#                    mpg                       cyl                        disp
# Mazda RX4         21.0 Here this is 6 completed. Here this is 160 completed.
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0                           Here this is 160 completed.
# Datsun 710        22.8 Here this is 4 completed. Here this is 108 completed.
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4 Here this is 6 completed. Here this is 258 completed.
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7 Here this is 8 completed. Here this is 360 completed.
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg I prefer to keep input data intact. It is up to OP if they want to overwrite the input data or keep as a separate new dataframe.

Answer (score -1):

```
DF = transform(ifelse(data$Column2 == "", data$Column2, sprintf('Here it is %s completed', data$Column2)))
DF <- data.frame (DF, data$Name, data$Column3)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: This should be done over several column, not a specific one

Comment: ya understood, wasnt aware of the which function...never done R...how does the which function scale?